# index undefined?

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I am retrieving a row from an SQL table using:

```
function fetchlevels($Competence_id){
    $this->query="SELECT * FROM levels WHERE comp_id=".$_REQUEST['levels'];
    $tulos=$this->suoritaKysely();
    return $tulos;
}
```

I call the function in the index using:

```
 $alllevels=$hr_object->fetchlevels($_GET['levels']);
 $page->assign('alllevels',$alllevels);
```

and then in my form I want to get the value of one of the columns:

```
$s=$this->alllevels;
echo $s['lvl2'];
```

But it tells me that

```
 Undefined index: lvl2 in C:\www\index\DevIT\forms\hr\competencelevels.php on line 6
```

However, when using print_r($s) I could see that there is an array with that column!

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [comp_id] => 1 [lvl1] => sas [lvl2] => scc [lvl3] => sxl [lvl4] => lxsi [lvl5] => azix ) )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That value is inside of an array within that array. So, no, it doesn't actually exist. To access it you need to use:

```
$s[0]['lvl2'];
```

Comment: Really didnt see that coming ! Thank you!

But is there any better design to use directly $s['lvl2']?